# How to limit the number of output lines in a given cell of the Ipython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Sometimes my Ipython notebooks crash because I left a `print` statement in a big loop or in a recursive function. The kernel shows `busy` and the `stop` button is usually unresponsive. Eventually Chrome asks me if I want to kill the page or wait.

Is there a way to limit the number of output lines in a given cell? Or any other way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 8):

You can suppress output using [this command](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tips.html#suppress-output):

```
‘;’ at the end of a line
```

Perhaps create a condition in your loop to suppress output past a certain threshold.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else stumbling across:

If you want to see some of the output rather than suppress the output entirely, there is an [extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) called [limit-output](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/wiki/Limit-Output).

You'll have to follow the installation instructions for the extensions at the first link.  Then I ran the following code to update the maximum number of characters output by each cell:

```py
from notebook.services.config import ConfigManager
cm = ConfigManager().update('notebook', {'limit_output': 10})
```

*Note: you'll need to run the block of code, then restart your notebook server entirely (not just the kernel) for the change to take effect.*

Results on jupyter v4.0.6 running a Python 2.7.12 kernel

```py
for i in range(0,100):
    print i

0
1
2
3
4

limit_output extension: Maximum message size exceeded
```

Comment: is there a way to do this for just the cell I am about to evaluate? or this type of things really require to restart the notebook and there is no way to set it on "per cell" basis?

Comment: From the docs, `the limit can also be set for an individual cell, using the cell's cell.metadata.limit_output.`

Comment: and how do you access and modify that value in Jupyter web interface???

Comment: in alternative I may ask: how do I modify cell.metadata.limit_output using code I can put in the cell itself?

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me - I'm using python 3.8 with vscode (1.61.0) editor of notebooks.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for vscode.